# Selenium Chrome WebDriver doesn't use proxy

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium webdriver to open a webpage and I set up a proxy for the driver to use. The code is listed below:

```
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
PROXY = "212.237.16.60:3128"  # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={PROXY}')


proxy = Proxy()
proxy.auto_detect = False
proxy.http_proxy = PROXY
proxy.sslProxy = PROXY
proxy.socks_proxy = PROXY
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
proxy.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, chrome_options=chrome_options,desired_capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get("https://whatismyipaddress.com")
```

The problem is that the web driver is not using the given proxy and it accesses the page with my normal IP. I already tried every type of code I could find on the internet and it didn't work. I also tried to set a proxy directly in my pc settings and when I open a normal chrome page it works fine (it's not a proxy server problem then), but if I open a page with the driver it still uses my normal IP and somehow bypasses the proxy. I also tried changing the proxy settings of the IDE (pycharm) and still it's not working. I'm out of ideas, could someone help me?

Answer (score 4):

This should work.

Code snippet-

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
PROXY = "212.237.16.60:3128"

#add proxy in chrome_options
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={PROXY}')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH,options=chrome_options)

#to check new IP
driver.get("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json")
```

Note:- `chrome_options` is deprecated now, you have to use `options` instead

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I've already tried this code and it doesn't work. At this point I don't think it's a code problem but more like something that has to do with the os or with the IDE, but I have no clue of what it could possibly be...

Comment: Have you tried using the [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) package.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, what would I need to do with it?

Comment: Install the package using `pip install webdriver-manager` and execute the code from [this](https://www.codepile.net/pile/XRb1ywKz) link.

Comment: I'll try that and let you know, thanks!

Comment: Had no luck with that either. It's still showing my IP address instead of the proxy.

Comment: At the end I just used firefox instead of chorme. I don't know why but I don't have this problem with firefox so I'll just stick with it.

Comment: A rare case indeed. Anyways, it got the job done :))

Comment: Connect to network
The network you are using may require you to visit its login page.